# Use Existing Environment Variable in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have an application built using Symfony 2.8. Now, the application config need to access an environment variable. This is not working in Symfony 2.8 (config.yml),

```
id: "%env(SOME_ID)%"
```

Is there a way to access it in config.yml file.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable yourself? I mean, is it a custom one created for your application?

Comment: yes it will auto set during app deployment

Comment: Give a try to name it `SYMFONY__SOME__ID` (notice the double `_`) and access it using `id: '%some.id%'`

Comment: `env()` is available since symfony 3.2

Comment: @cid I cant change the env variable name it is defined already and used in other place.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration) in combination with [getenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) this can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Symfony 2.8, you can declare some external parameters from your server :

- With Apache, with the [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html) directive:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ...
      SetEnv    SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER user
      SetEnv    SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD secret
      SetEnv    SYMFONY__SOME_ID 1234
      ...
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- With Nginx, with [fastcgi_param](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param) directive:

  ```
  server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
      ...
      fastcgi_param SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER user;
      fastcgi_param SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD secret;
      fastcgi_param SYMFONY__SOME_ID 1234
      ...
    }
  }
  ```

These environment variables will be passed to the container, with some transformations:

- `SYMFONY__` prefix is removed
- Parameter name is lowercased
- Double underscores `__` are replaced with a period.

So you can use them as is:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    dbname:   symfony_project
    user:     '%database.user%'
    password: '%database.password%'
some_config:
    id: '%some_id%'
```

You can also pass some PHP constants :

```
parameters:
    some_id: "@=constant('SOME_ID')"
    my_class.some_id: "@=constant('My_Class::SOME_ID')"
```

Hope that helps !